# crypt() function returns different result size on different server

Tags: php, password-encryption

I need to transfer some hashed password on a new server from old one. 
Old server has php 5.4.4 and crypt() function on password return a string 102 characters.
My new server has php 5.5.7 and crypt function return a string of 34 characters.
On both server, crypt is called without parameters

```
crypt($password);
```

On user login (on old server) i use this code:

```
crypt($_POST['password'], $hash_password) == $hash_password
```

Now, if i copy hash passwords to new hosting, and i call that method for check if password is correct, password never match.
How can i do to make the same type of hashing to that different server?

this is an example of two crypted password:

on old server:

```
$6$kcPF.fPojej2$YF5Ui0nP8t5Wc0JVVEI9.JD2l/ZyLQGL6T5RN3E5oz3GGiSZoTBsbocMggLkdlBhO6Xe7cGdepW7bo6mKFjYx1
```

on new server

```
$1$Sz1cDmU0$Z0uoEwnXH1NokqPwwQJsp/
```

Comment: did you check the value of constants like CRYPT_BLOWFISH or CRYPT_SHA256 (or the appropriate one for what you are using) to see if you have the same algorithms available? (you can see them listed on the man page)

Comment: show us please one of old and one of new hash examples.

Comment: I see that you are ignoring what I'm saying but maybe others will find this useful: if you check the two hashes you see that one starts with $6$ (specific for sha512) and the other with $1$ (specific for md5) so it's obvious that different algorithms are used

Comment: @mishu i've not ignored your suggestion! i've checked the php.ini files, and they contains the same crypted algorithms. I've noticed now that all passwords on old server contains $6$ value! Now i try to change haxsh algorithm

Comment: @giozh, yeah) I wanted you see that) all hashes started their algorithm :)

Answer (score 2):

The old server is using the SHA256 algorithm to create hashes, but the new server doesn't seem to support it; in other words, the constant `CRYPT_SHA512` is `0`.

Depending on how PHP is installed on the new server you may have to check whether `libcrypt` is recent enough or contact the hosting company that provides the server.